How does French Canada Locale work in Android?
I need to create behaviour specifically for Quebec; which is a French province in English Canada.  There is a French Canada Locale in the device API; but not Quebec.  I'm assuming this is based on the system language choice.  The problem is that many people in Quebec are English speakers and will have their devices set to English language.
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale#CANADA_FRENCH
How does this work? I can easily get the device location if the user has location services enabled; and I thought there might be an option with play store configurations or Remote Config attributes but they don't drill down into provinces; only countries IE Canada.
What about something from HTTPS?

"I need to create behaviour specifically for Quebec ; which is a French province" Do you mean people physically in Quebec, or people who speak Quebec French (as opposed to some other variety of Canadian French) regardless of where they are in the world?

Note that the answer differs depending on that question; this question cannot be answered without knowing which you need.

Would be location-based.  However I found some simpler solutions; we can also use Firebase Analytics audiences.
